# Android - Room Repository and AsyncTask, how to use query to get back data from table

Tags: android

How do you get data from your Room entity using AsyncTask? I've been looking through the answers regarding AsyncTask but I don't get it.

This is my Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface BudgetDao {

    @Insert
    public void insert (Budget budget);

    @Update
    public void update (Budget budget);

    @Query("SELECT id FROM budget_table WHERE category = :category AND date = :date")
    int getId(String category, String date);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM budget_table")
    LiveData<List<Budget>> getAllBudgets();

    @Query("SELECT category FROM budget_table")
    List<String> getAllCategories();

}
```

How do I get the AsyncTask in my repository to return a list of strings? Right now the code is `public void getAllCategories() {new getAllCatsAsyncTask(mBudgetDao).execute();` When I change the void to List, an error shows that I can't return a list of strings

My Repository:

```
public class BudgetRepository {

    private BudgetDao mBudgetDao;
    private LiveData<List<Budget>> mAllBudgets;

    BudgetRepository(Application application) {
        BudgetRoomDatabase db = BudgetRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mBudgetDao = db.budgetDao();
        mAllBudgets = mBudgetDao.getAllBudgets();
    }

    LiveData<List<Budget>> getAllBudgets() {return mAllBudgets;}
    public void insert (Budget budget) {new insertAsyncTask(mBudgetDao).execute(budget);}
    public void getAllCategories() {new getAllCatsAsyncTask(mBudgetDao).execute();}
    //How do I return a list of strings?


    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Budget, Void, Void> {
        //code
    }

    private class getAllCatsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private BudgetDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        getAllCatsAsyncTask(BudgetDao dao) {mAsyncTaskDao = dao;}

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return mAsyncTaskDao.getAllCategories();
        }

    }

}
```

In my ViewModel:

```
public class BudgetViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private BudgetRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Budget>> mAllBudgets;

    public BudgetViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new BudgetRepository(application);
        mAllBudgets = mRepository.getAllBudgets();
    }

    LiveData<List<Budget>> getAllBudgets() {return mAllBudgets;}

    public void insert(Budget budget) {mRepository.insert(budget);}

    public List<String> getAllCats() { return mRepository.getAllCategories();} 
    //Android Studios show incompatible types (Void vs List<String>)
```

Right now, in my ViewModel, `mRepository.getAllCategories` does not return a list of strings.

Do I have to call `onPostExecute` in my AsyncTask? How do I link the results from `onPostExecute` so that `getAllCategories` can return a list of strings in my AsyncTask? Or is there a better way to call for queries from my Dao?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DisplayData displayData=new DisplayData(studentDatabase);
    displayData.execute();
 }
/**
 * this method display student.
 */
private void DisplayStudent() {
    mStudentList.addAll(studentDatabase.studentDao().getStudent());
}


  private class DisplayData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    private StudentDatabase studentDatabase;

    public DisplayData(StudentDatabase studentDatabase) {
        this.studentDatabase = studentDatabase;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DisplayStudent();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        mDialog.dismiss();
        mStu_adapter=new StudentAdapter(mStudentList,getApplicationContext());
        mStu_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRvStudent.setAdapter(mStu_adapter);
        DividerItemDecoration divider=new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        divider.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.divider));
        mRvStudent.addItemDecoration(divider);
   }
}
```

if you want to allow on **mainThread**  then set this line.

```
      db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database-name").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
```